# WPF TextBox, Updating Text Property Resets Cursor Position

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF application, if the `Text` property of a `TextBox` control is programmatically updated while the user still has focus on the control (say, with a `TextChanged` or `KeyUp` event), is it possible to maintain the position of the user's cursor after the `Text` property has been updated?

In normal circumstances, if the `Text` property is updated, and user has focus on the control, the cursor is simply reset back to the start of the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to maintain the user's cursor position after a value change. Let us examine a scenario where this can be used.

Consider a `TextBox` control where you only want the user to enter alphanumeric value, and have all other characters removed.

You might have some `XAML` looking like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myInput" Margin="72,95,0,0" TextChanged="clearInputHandler" />
```

... and a `C#` handler, like this:

```
private void clearInputHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    string validInput = Regex.Replace(myInput.Text, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
    myInput.Text = validInput;
}
```

However, this suffers from the problem where the cursor position will be set to the beginning of the input if the `Text` property is updated.

To correct this issue, use the `CaretIndex` property, which grabs the location of the user's cursor:

```
private void clearInputHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    int oldIndex = myInput.CaretIndex;
    string oldValue = myInput.Text;
    string validInput = Regex.Replace(myInput.Text, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
    myInput.Text = validInput;

    if (!oldValue.Equals(validInput)) 
    {
        myInput.CaretIndex = oldIndex - 1;
    }
}
```

A few notes on the above code sample:

1. Notice how the `CaretIndex` property is gathered **before** any changes are made to the `Text` property. This way we know where the cursor is before anything is changed.
2. The original value of the `TextBox` is saved. See #4.
3. The `Text` property is set again, **before** the user's cursor position is changed.
4. The `if` statement at the bottom is only run if the regex changes the text it was given. The cursor position, by nature will automatically advance to the next space, as the user types valid input. However, if the user enters an invalid character, the `oldIndex` registers the next space the cursor should normally go, the regex removes the invalid character, and the `if` statement is run, and moves back once space, since the invalid character was removed.

Comment: Where is `index` defined?  Did you mean to put `oldIndex`?